# Given two primes $p$, $q$ and their product $pq$, find $\phi(pq)$ mod $p + q$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is actually from a past year exam question for a computer security module, which I am doing to prepare for my upcoming test.

The question provides $pq = 1669806207577$ (for ease of reference, I will refer to it as $n$.

Define $\phi(n) = n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right) \cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$ as the the Euler Phi function, where $p_1, \cdots, p_k$ are the prime factors of $n$.

The question asks us to find $\phi(pq) \text{ mod } (p+q)$.

My approach is as follows,

$\phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq - p - q + 1$

I have tried to express $2pq$ as $(p+q)^2 - p^2 - q^2$ and substituting it to the above, such that,

$\phi(pq) = pq - p - q + 1 = [(p+q)^2- p^2 - q^2]/2 - (p+q) + 1$.

But now, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You have $\varphi(pq)=pq+1-(p+q)\equiv pq+1\pmod {p+q}$ already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basis of the RSA cryptosystem and there is no known parametric solution for this in terms of $p$ and $q$ which is less than $pq+1$ otherwise you will have cracked the RSA encryption system. So the best you can hope for is a brute force computer attack to factorize $n$ and find $p$ and $q$.